# Ways to allows requests to APIs only from internal in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, api

I know CURL & HTTP authentication to allow API calls only from certain requests.

I have something like this

```
www.mysite.com/list

www.mysite.com/api
```

`list` page calls the `api` page using jQuery Ajax post request and `api` page echos jSON response.

I am already checking HTTP referrer to verify Post requests come from certain origins but these requests can be forged.

I cannot use $_SERVER['remote_addr'] as this will check the client ip not the source ip of the API request.

As both the pages are hosted in the same web server and in the same hostname, its not possible to restrict based on hostname or IP address.

```
I am aware of some alternatives like

cURL with HTTP Authentication.
```

Encryption of jSON response and Decrypting before printing.

But is there any way to restrict these API pages to securely block access from outside the server or hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to restrict access to "Joe Random user who is visiting your website with a web browser".

Not really.

There's no way to reliably determine that the client is a regular web browser. Anyone writing some other client to access your API can easily have it visit your website and get whatever tokens they need to prove that.

The best you can do is some sort of heuristic approach that looks for unusual traffic patterns (such as unusually high numbers of similar requests from one source, or ones which have very stable intervals between requests).  You'll get false positives and negatives from that kind of approach though.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you are trying to invent csrf tokens. But with little modification:

You should store generated token in session/cookie before rendering `/list`. I am not sure whether jQuery send session/cookie with ajax request by default, but I think it should not be a big problem if not, to append it.

When you will process `/api` request you should validate cookie/session also for the token existance.